# how to update old records with computed field with store = True

Tags: python, xml, odoo, odoo-10, calculated-columns

I want to update the "on_hand_qty" field of existing record

```
 _inherit="product.product"
     
    on_hand_qty=fields.Float('onhand', compute='copy_quant' ,store=True)
    
    
    @api.constrains('qty_available')
    def copy_quant(self):
        for rec in self:
            rec.on_hand_qty = rec.qty_available
```

I want this field with store =True
but this field is not updated in old records with store= True. please suggest how to achieve this.

Comment: Why do you use `api.constrains` as decorator instead of `api.depends`?

Answer (score 1):

user10810227

Make the `related`  field of `qty_available`

```
on_hand_qty=fields.Float(related='qty_available', string="Your Field")
```